Find positive $p,q$ such that $p+q=1$ and $p-p^n=q-q^n$ for natural $n\geq 3$
I would appreciate if somebody could help me with the following problem
Q: For a natural number $n$ of $3$ or more and a positive number $p$ and $q$ with $p+q=1$, find $p$ and $q$ that satisfy
$$p-p^n=q-q^n$$
My work: By taking $f(x)=x-x^n$ and using the upward convex nature and symmetry of the function $f(x)$ in the interval $(0,1)$,
$$f(x)=f(1-x)$$ The conclusion is that $\dfrac 12$ is the only $x$ that satisfies, but this lacks rigor. Please provide multiple approaches.

$$
p-p^n-[q-q^n]=p-q+(q^n-p^n)=(q-p)(-1+q^{n-1}+pq^{n-2}+\dots+p^{n-1}q+p^{n-1})=(1-2p)(-1+A)
$$
Now $1-2p$ changes the sign only at $p=1/2$, and at the same time
\begin{align}
A&:=q^{n-1}+pq^{n-2}+\dots+p^{n-1}q+p^{n-1}\le 
q^{n-1}+pq^{n-2}+pq^{n-3}+\dots+pq+p
\\ &=
q^{n-1}+p(1+q+\dots+q^{n-2})=q^{n-1}+p\frac{1-q^{n-1}}{1-q}=
q^{n-1}+(1-q^{n-1})=1
\end{align}
since $q=1-p$ and $0<p<1$ so $p^k\le p$ for $k\ge 1$. Therefore $p-p^n-[q-q^n]$ changes the sign only once.

$$p-q=p^n-q^n$$
$$\implies (p-q)=(p-q)(p^n + p^{n-1}q + p^{n-2}q^2+...q^n)$$
$$\implies (p-q)(1-p^n-p^{n-1}q-p^{n-2}q^2-...-q^n)=0$$
Hence either $p=q$:-
$p+q=1\implies 2p=1\implies p=\frac{1}{2}$
I missed the fact that $p,q>0$.OP, if you want it can be easily proven that
$$1=(p+q)^{n}={\sum_{k=0}^{n}} {^{n}C_k}\ p^{n-k}q^k>(p^n-p^{n-1}q-p^{n-2}q^2-...-q^n)$$
So only answer is $p=q=\frac{1}{2}$
(Taking $p,q\in R$)
Or:-
$$1=p^n + p^{n-1}(1-p)+p^{n-2}(1-p)^2+...(1-p)^n$$
Taking $1$ from this side and subtracting from $p^n$,
$$\implies 0=(p^n-1)+ (1-p)[p^{n-1}+p^{n-2}(1-p)+...(1-p)^{n-1}]$$
$$\implies 0=(p-1)(p^{n-1}+p^{n-2}+p^{n-3}+...1) +(1-p)[p^{n-1}+p^{n-2}(1-p)+...(1-p)^{n-1}]$$
$$0=(p-1)\bigg[\bigg(p^{n-1}+p^{n-2}+p^{n-3}+...1\bigg)-\bigg(p^{n-1}+p^{n-2}(1-p)+...(1-p)^{n-1}\bigg)\bigg]$$
Hence either $p=1,q=0$
Or
$$0=\sum_{k=1}^n p^{n-k} - \sum_{k=1}^n p^{n-k}(1-p)^k $$
Hence we can take $p=0,q=1$
Thus we get $3$ pairs, $p=q=\frac{1}{2};p=0,q=1;p=1,q=0$

$p=0$ and $q=0$ are excluded by "a positive number p and q" -- $0$ is not positive.

Oh then I didn't see that @m-stgt. Heh random time waste.  But other than that it's alright I guess.

@ Gwen -- sorry, tl;dr -- I've checked only by plotting with $n=3, 4, 5, 15$ and yes, for this four samples it's ok ;)

As $p, q > 0$ then $1=(p + q)^{n-1} = \sum p^kq^k{n-1\choose k }  > \sum p^kq^k$ is another way of showing that if $p^{n-1}q + .... + pq^{n-1}$ can't be equal to $1$.

@fleablood I totally overlooked the fact that it said only positive p and q. I'm editing it in the answer

I admit, it might be harder if we allow negatives.

@fleablood you mean negative n?

No.  I meant you came up with a way of solving $1-p^{n-1}q - .... -pq^{n-1} =0$ that looked rather impressive.  I made a comment that that if we know $p, q> 0$ then $(p+q)^{n} >p^{n-1}q+ .... + pq^{n-1}$ is much easier.  But I concede if we may allow $p,q$ to be negative my easy vs. your impressive might not be all that easier.

It feels so great for a high school student like me when my method is praised by a literal god of Mathematics Stack exchange. Thank you :)

Let f(x) = x - x^n and g(x) = f(x) - f(1-x), and you are asking whether there is 0 <= x <= 1 with g(x) = 0.
g(x) and g(1-x) have opposite sign, and g(x) is continuous, so if g(x) ≠ 0 for any 0 <= x < 1/2 then there is x < x’ < 1-x with g(x’) = 0. And if there is no such x then we have many x’ with g(x’) = 0.
Your particular form p - p^n is quite irrelevant, all that matters is that you have a continuous function.

How do we find exact values of $x$ where $g(x)=0$? (This is what OP asked for.)

Factoring both sides of $p-p^{n}=q-q^{n}$ yields $p(1-p)\sum_{k\lt n-1}^{}p^{k}=q(1-q)\sum_{k\lt n-1}^{}q^{k}$. Since $p=1-q$ and $q=1-p$, we may cancel the terms $p(1-p)$ and $q(1-q)$ from both sides. Then, we have $\sum_{k\lt n-1}^{}p^{k}=\sum_{k\lt n-1}^{}q^{k}$. This can't happen unless $p=q$.
